# Log shell output

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I would like to log all interactive shell output. Whenever I use a terminal everything printed to the terminal would also be put in a file.

I tried

```
bash|tee log.txt
```

Which mostly worked. The only problem is that some commands such as man pages don't display correctly. I would guess that they test for an interactive shell and don't find one?

Any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `script` and `scriptreplay`.

From `man script`

```
DESCRIPTION
       script makes a typescript of everything displayed on your terminal.  It is useful for students who need a hardcopy record
       of an interactive session as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file can be printed out later with lpr(1).

       If the argument file is given, script saves the dialogue in this file.  If no filename is given, the dialogue is saved in
       the file typescript.
```

You can view the session log with e.g `cat`, `less`, `vim`...
Note however that using things like `man` or `vim` during your session produces a lot of escape characters that scramble up the output. I don't know of any way to avoid that.

If you need to record output of programs that overwrite the screen, you will also want to record timing information

```
script --timing=mytiming mysession
```

Doing so allows you to play back the session as it happened in time with

```
scriptreplay -t mytiming -s mysession
```

The parameter `-d` can specify a speed-up/slow-down factor.